# Subject.next() not firing from inside observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

**service.ts**

```
constructor() {
    this.cartUpdate = new BehaviorSubject<Array<AppCartItem>>([]);
    // this.cartUpdate.subscribe((items) => {   // #### 1
    //   console.log('Service Items : ', items);
    // });
}
add(item) : Observable<Array<AppItem>> {
    return this.get().pipe(
      switchMap(cartItems => {
        let index = cartItems.findIndex(i => i.item.id == item.id);
        if(index == -1) {
          cartItems.push({ item });
        }
        return this.updateUser({ 'cart': cartItems })
        .pipe(
          map(() => {
            return cartItems;
          })
        )
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log('Error : ', err);
        return throwError(null);
      })
    ).pipe(
      map(cartItems => {
        this.updateCart(cartItems);
        return cartItems;
      })
    )
}

updateCart(items) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.cartUpdate.next(items);  // #### 3
    }, 1000);
}
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.cartUpdate.subscribe((items) => {  // ####4
    console.log('Items : ', items);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('Error : ', err);
  });
}
```

I have provided the code for service and component.
Initially, in the component the subscribe is triggering. No issue in that. **#### 4**

Now, the add method in service.ts also should trigger the observable after adding the item. **#### 3**

But the subscribe in component is not triggering for the emit. **#### 3**

Whereas the subscribe in the constructor for the same Subject is working. **#### 1**

I am having trouble in figuring out why the subscribe in the component is not working

Answer (score 0):

Some approaches need to be corrected,
Subscriptions always respond when there is a change in value.
Made an example for you, follow this one

**Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceService {
cartUpdate = new BehaviorSubject([]);
constructor() { }
add() {
    this.cartUpdate.next([1,2,1])
    this.updateCart([2, 12]);
    return this.cartUpdate.asObservable();
}
updateCart(items) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('calling');
        this.cartUpdate.next(items);
        console.log(this.cartUpdate);
    }, 3000);
}
}
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.service.add().subscribe(res =>{
  this.response = res;
  console.log('Hi'+ res);
})
}
```

**Demo:**
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zeamcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)